# How to edit/delete array data use button in php form?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database

I have array data inserted from dynamic field form. Here is my file

**dbconn.php**

```
<?php
$mysql_db_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_db_user = "root";
$mysql_db_password = "";
$mysql_db_database = "try";

$connection = mysql_connect($mysql_db_hostname, $mysql_db_user, $mysql_db_password) or die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_db_database, $connection) or die("Could not select database");
?>
```

and it will show and input it from this file

**index.php**

```
<?php
require("dbconn.php");
?>

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
$(function(){
 $('#add_field').click(function(){
 counter += 1;
 $('#container').append(
 '<div><strong>Hobby No. ' + counter + '</strong><br />'
 + '<input id="field_' + counter + '" name="dynfields[]' + '" type="text" required /> <button type="button" href="#" class="remove_field">-</button><br /></div>' );

 });
 $('#container').on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); counter--;
    })
});
</script>

<body>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit_val'])) {
if ($_POST['dynfields']) {
foreach ( $_POST['dynfields'] as $key=>$value ) {
$values = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO prefix (ipfx,cid) VALUES ('$values','123')", $connection );

}
}

echo "<i><h2><strong>" . count($_POST['dynfields']) . "</strong> Hobbies Added</h2></i>";

 mysql_close();
}
?>
<?php 
if (!isset($_POST['submit_val'])) { ?>

<?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM prefix WHERE cid = '123'")
            or die(mysql_error());

            echo "<form method='post'><table border='1' cellpadding='7'>";
            echo "<tr>
                    <th><font color='Red'>CID</font></th>
                    <th><font color='Red'>Hobi</font></th>
                  </tr>";

            $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
            echo '<tr>
                        <td><font color="#333">' . strtoupper($row['cid']) . '</font></td><td><table>';

            $no=1;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))
            {
                echo '
                        <tr><td><input type="text" value="' . $row['ipfx'] . '"><hr></td></tr>';

                        ////////////////////////////////////


                        }

                echo '</table></td></tr></table>';
            $no++;
        ?>
 <h1>Add your Hobbies</h1>
 <form method="post" action="">

 <div id="container">
 <strong>Hobby No. 1</strong><br /><input id="field_1" name="dynfields[]" type="text" required/> <button type="button" id="add_field" href="#">+</button>
 </div><br />

 <input type="submit" name="submit_val" value="Submit" />
 </form>
<?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

My question is how to edit/delete that data with onclick button in php form?

Thank you

Comment: All you people still using `mysql` functions are gonna have a nice time when php7 becomes mainstream <3

Answer (score 0):

There are number of ways for doing it.

1. you can use ajax for submitting data for delete/edit
2. or you can submit it directly

For point 1 - First of all add edit/delete button with each row with unique id(you can do it using your ipfx number with any text) & then you can call any js method for submitting it & change it dynamically. while submitting it, you can collect data using that unique id & can easily manipulate it by ajax submission.

Like this - inside loop

```
<button id="edit_<?php echo $row['ipfx']; ?>" name="edit" type="button" onclick='edit_data("<?php echo $row['ipfx']; ?>");'/>
```

in js part -

```
function edit_data(id){
var data1 = $('#id').val();
 $.ajax({
     "data": {"data1": data1},
     "type": "POST",
     "url": "test.php"
 });
}
```

Hope now you can do complete it quite easily.

Comment: Please read about jquery ajax submission, then it will be clear to you. Inside $.ajax({}) you can pass data & can call any other php method/file for submitting your form & take action for it.

Comment: Check updated code inside ajax call, change data portion & url portion for your specified work